# Can I send someone who wants to meet me about a business contract on a "wild goose chase"?

Tags: spam

I have received an unsolicited electronic message (email sent through my web site) touting for business.

The sender is in breach of the Unsolicited Electronic Messages Act, and I hate spam.  He also represents a real company in my part of the world.

Were I to set up a meeting with him, in a place which does not exist, and with no intention of actually transacting or meeting with him, would I be acting illegally ?   (I happen to live in New Zealand, but I'm interested in perspectives of other common-law countries as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be liable for [deceit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tort_of_deceit), specifically leading him to believe that you intend to be at a particular place at a particular time to discuss business, but actually you do not so intend.

The measure of damages for deceit is to ask what would have happened had you not deceived him. Absent your deceit, he would not have traveled to wherever he thought he was meeting you. Therefore, you would have to compensate him for his travel expenses to get to the non-existent place and possibly for lost income if he has given up other work to spend time attempting to see you.

You may also commit a criminal offence such as causing a loss by deception: [Crimes Act 1961 (NZ), s 240](http://www.legislation.govt.nz/act/public/1961/0043/latest/DLM330275.html).

Comment: Thank you, interesting POV.   Would the "clean hands" doctrine bar the bringing of a claim for deceipt ?  (they deceived me first).  Also, thanks for reminding me of section 240.

Comment: The 'clean hands' doctrine requires the plaintiff's bad behaviour to relate to the subject matter of their complaint. In this case, if I understand it correctly, the businessman deceived you and then you would deceive him in retaliation. The clean hands doctrine doesn't excuse retaliation. If it did, then you could run over protesters with your car and claim 'unclean hands'. ( https://www.reddit.com/r/legaladvice/comments/4ts5hk/can_i_run_over_protesters_megathread/ )